# Unit list -or- next/prev unit?

Tags: keyboard, alpha-centauri, alien-crossfire

In later entries in the series such as Civilization V, the player is able to use `Period` and `Comma` to cycle through all unwaited units, and [can easily access a list of **all** units](https://steamcommunity.com/app/65980/discussions/0/619569608653800630/#forum_op_619569608653800630), as well.

Are either of these capabilities present in Sid Meier's Alpha Centauri or its Alien Crossfire expansion?

I'm tired of being in-doubt as to just how many units I've got floating around — enumerating them all one *spoonful* at a time from the Base Information's "Support" list is time-consuming, painful, and misses tamed Mind Worm boils anyway. I would *really* like to see either a list of all allied units, or a way to manually cycle between them (even if only the unwaited units—I'd be fine to completely eschew automation, since it's not very good in many cases anyway).

Answer (score 1):

According to the 220 pages physical manual (good old times), In french version, hitting V on the map allow you to go to the next unit.
No mention is made of a way to go to the previous unit.
Yet according to the key mapping at the end, V key is used for 'center on active unit'.

Other possibility working on the same pattern, the W key is used for 'wait' (act later). I can see how you can use it for cycling (forward only) through your units.

Sorry for french version...
[image: French version, sorry]

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't see anything applicable in [this](https://www.ign.com/articles/2005/01/06/sid-meiers-alpha-centauri-hotkey-faq-373466) quite extensive keyboard shortcut overview.

It's been a while since I played SMAC, but I would simply **issue orders to each idle unit**, then, if I recall correctly, the game would automatically change focus to the next *idle* unit automatically. In some cases I would issue further movement or another action (like terraforming or roadbuilding), in others the destination would be a city to fortify or sentry in. An action or a guard mode removes the unit from this 'next' cycle, so you'd eventually go through every one of your idle units during the turn.

As far as **tallies** of units are concerned, I'd passively build that up in memory after going through a few turns. There's usually logic and a grand scheme that you yourself are best familiar with, so sticking to those patterns will make it easy to reacquaint yourself with your save game if you pick it up after a few weeks or months. I'd for example have a minimum number of guard units of a few specific types in each colony, so I know that if there's a colony, these will be inside. And any unit that has completed something will automatically end up back in the idle queue above.

Comment: My copy of SMAC is insisting on crashing every time I run it, but I'm sure there's a key for going to the next idle unit.  In Colonization, it's "w"; my muscle memory for SMAC says it's "n", but as I noted, I can't check it.  I'm also sure there's a report for unit tallies: it's been a part of the series since the original Civilization.